# HTA File Caching causing major issues

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, caching, hta

I have a JavaScript function which first of all fetches the value of a label element, which is an ID for a database entry. These ID's then get sent to a ASP page which fetch an images save location from the database.

This save location information for each selected image is then sent to a ASP.NET page which splits each image save location and rotates the images accordingly. This all works perfect, my only issue is that the images will not update until I reopen the HTA file.

- Refreshing does not work, as seen in the video.
- The files HAVE rotated as you can see in the video at the bottom
- [Here is the link to the video!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAgv2MnL_C8)

Here is my JavaScript which does the rotating:

```
function doRotate(dir,obj)
{
    var http = getHTTPObject();
    var http2 = getHTTPObject();
    ids = fetchSelection().toString();

    //Make button animate, visual aid that it is working
    obj.src = "http://localhost/nightclub_photography/images/buttons/"+dir+"_animated.gif";

    http.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        //Fetch the save location of selected images
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            //Create URL string to send to rotate script
            var locs = http.responseText;
            locs = locs.split(",");

            //Start of URL 
            var url = "http://localhost/nightclub_photography/net/rotate_script.aspx?dir=" + dir;

            for (var i=0; i < locs.length-1; i++)
            {
                url = url + "&t=" + locs[i];
            }
            //Add random math
            url = url + "&k=" + Math.random();

            http2.onreadystatechange = function() 
            {                   
                if (http2.readyState == 4 && http2.status == 200)
                {

                    //Stop animated button
                    obj.src = "http://localhost/nightclub_photography/images/buttons/"+dir+".png";

                    //Split id's
                    var idsSplit = ids.split(",");
                    for (var k=0; k < idsSplit.length; k++) {
                        reapplyStyle(idsSplit[k]);
                    }
                }
            }
            http2.open("GET", url);
            http2.send();
        }
    }
    http.open("GET", "http://localhost/nightclub_photography/asp/returnDatabaseData.asp?ids="+ids+"&k=" + Math.random());
    http.send();
}
```

I also have a function which reapplies (well, should do) the background image, which should reload the rotated images. Although reloading the page doesn't work, so I can't see that function working either, but that's a different issue. Here is the function:

```
function reapplyStyle(id) {
    var background = doc(id+"_label").style.backgroundImage;
    doc(id+"_label").style.backgroundImage = background;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a caching problem, have you tried making the image url unique. Try something like this:

```
ts = new Date().getTime();
obj.src = "http://localhost/nightclub_photography/images/buttons/"+dir+".png?timestamp=" + ts;
```

Comment: The way I display the content is pull it all in using Ajax as you can't load different pages with an HTA file unless you use an iframe. So I have been pulling the content in with a unique number on the end so thought that would of worked. I will try adding a unique number in the end of each photo as well though when I get home thanks, didn't think of that

Comment: The "proper" way to fix this would be to set the Cache-Control response header on the images appropriately, but adding a unique number to the end of the URLs is a simple workaround.